# Correct term for "minor matrix"

Tags: matrices, terminology

If I get it right, the minor $M_{i,j}$ for an element $a_{i,j}$ of a matrix A is the determinant of the matrix created from $A$ by excluding the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column. But what is a proper term for such a submatrix without referring to its determinant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no standard name for it; I've looked in several different sources and the minor is always defined as the "determinant of the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix taken by removing the $i$'th row and $j$'th column". If you have a need for it, define it in your work and then refer to your definition.